# Cassandra SStableLoader Streaming Error Broken pipe

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to use SSTableLoader to migrate tables from a Cassandra 2.1 cluster to a Cassandra 3.11 and while some SStables are loaded successfully, I keep hitting weird errors with others.
I'm trying to repeatedly load the same SSTables, sometimes I get a generic

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed

Other times

> org.apache.cassandra.io.FSReadError: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe

However, if I check in system.log I always find this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No column name component found in
>   cell name

Tried searching for the error above, did not find any helpful details.

I tried nodetool repair on the tables in the 2.x cluster but after a couple of hours it looks like it's still not done. I would try to use nodetool scrub but not sure if this will result in data loss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the sstable format changed in Cassandra 3.0 and so you can't just stream sstables in the 2.1 format to a 3.x node as the sstable format.

The official (and better) way is that you would first need to upgrade your node(s) to a newer C* version and then run `nodetool upgradesstables -a`.

Comment: I cannot upgrade the 2.1 nodes to 3.x, I copy them to 3.11 nodes and try to load them, how can I upgrade the sstables if I cannot import them into 3.11 first?. Also I found this in the official documentation: 
Bulkloading SSTables created in versions prior to Cassandra 3.0 is supported only in Cassandra 3.0.5 and later.  This suggests that importing should be supported, and some sstables indeed can be imported.

Comment: An update here, I successfully loaded over 50 sstables from one DB to another, It's just 2 column stores that give this error and not all sstables,just most of them.